# Generate count value in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to find out the number of users whose age is between 19 and 60. Below is the sample queries

```
loadtable = load '/user/userdetails.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,age:int);

filteredvalues = filter loadtable  by (age > 19 AND  age < 60);

grouped = GROUP filteredvalues ALL;

count = foreach grouped generate COUNT(grouped);
```

I am getting the following error "**Invalid scalar projection: grouped : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to count the filteredvalues instead of grouped.

```
total = foreach grouped generate COUNT(filteredvalues);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you explain in brief why we are doing the count on filteredvalues and not group

Comment: @subhrendu grouped is a bag with tuples(filtervalues) in it.You count the tuples in each bag(group) but not the bag itself.If you group by specific field/fields,you will get multiple bags with tuples in it and then you get a count for each group.In this case we are counting all and so only 1 group.

Comment: Thanks. Understood

Answer (score 1):

Sample **userdetails.txt:**

```
Robin,85

BOB,55

Maya,23

Sara,45

David,23

Maggy,22

Robert,75

Syam,23

Mary,25

Saran,17

Stacy,19

Kelly,22
```

---

**Code:**

```
grunt> loadtable = load '/user/userdetails.txt' using PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,age:int);

grunt> filteredvalues = filter loadtable  by (age > 19 AND  age < 60);

grunt> grouped = GROUP filteredvalues ALL;

grunt> count = foreach grouped generate COUNT(filteredvalues);

grunt> dump count;
```

> **Always count is performed before group relation or bag otherwise it throws:**
>   "Invalid scalar projection: grouped : A column needs to be projected
>   from a relation for it to be used as a scalar"

---